# Kony Visualizer setting image to photo which was just taken

Tags: image, camera, widget, temenos-quantum

I have a form on Kony visualizer with a Camera widget and an Image2 widget.  How can I set the Image2 widget to display the image taken by the Camera widget.

I have a js controller for this form so if there's a way to do it via that, please let me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out with some help from the Kony Forums:

If you have camera(cam1) and image(img) widgets added to the form(frmHome), then you can invoke below snippet in camera onCapture event, to set the image widget with the image taken by camera widget.

```
frmHome.img.rawBytes = frmHome.cam1.rawBytes;
```

Hope this helps other who run into this problem!